# Jinja2 Import from Parent Directory

Tags: jinja2

I have a text file where I am using something like

```
{% import '/macros/macro.macro' as macro with context %}
```

However, I would like to import a macro from a folder in the parent directory. Not sure how to approach this. I have tried using ~ and .. with no success. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You can use relative paths, starting from Jinja2's template_directory